# Why classpath=/tomcat_lib/ doesn't work

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

HI guys,

There is an abc.jar under /tomcat_lib. I need use this in my def.java

I tired

> javac -classpath /tomcat_lib/ -d
>   ../classes def.java

but it doesn't work

But if it works if I use

> javac -classpath /tomcat_lib/abc.jar
>   -d ....

Can anyone help explain it?

Comment: If you want to do this for a group of jar files, checkout the section "Understanding class path wildcards" here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a jar to your classpath, you need to specify the path up to and including the .jar file.

Quoting the [official Java SE 6 documentation at Oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> Each [item in your classpath] should
>   end with a filename or directory
>   depending on what you are setting the
>   class path to:
>
> - **For a .jar or .zip file
>     that contains .class files, the class
>     path ends with the name of the .zip or
>     .jar file.**
> - For .class files in an
>     unnamed package, the class path ends
>     with the directory that contains the
>     .class files.
> - For .class files in a
>     named package, the class path ends
>     with the directory that contains the
>     "root" package (the first package in
>     the full package name).

...and from the "Folders and Archive Files" section of the [same documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> When classes are stored in a directory
>   (folder), like
>   c:\java\MyClasses\utility\myapp, then
>   the class path entry points to the
>   directory that contains the first
>   element of the package name. (in this
>   case, C:\java\MyClasses, since the
>   package name is utility.myapp.)
>
> **But when classes are stored in an
>   archive file (a .zip or .jar file) the
>   class path entry is the path to and
>   including the .zip or .jar file.**

Comment: Perfect.  I  had the same question.  Searching StackOverFlow is much better than posting a new question.